# Why did the F-14 sweep wing control have a cover?

Tags: military, wing-sweep, f-14

I learned from Top Gun maverick that the F-14 had what seemed to be a metal cover in front of the wing sweep adjustment cursor. Maverick modifies the sweep angle twice, and twice needs to first lift the cover, then actuate the sweep angle control.

It seems to be a very clunky interface to me. What's the purpose of the cover, and why was it designed that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During normal operation the wing sweep angle is controlled automatically by the [CADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-14_CADC).

The manual override would only be in use in case of CADC malfunction or on the ground to "oversweep" the wings over the horizontal stabilators.

The manual override control is in fact protected by a guard in order to prevent accidental usage/activation (similar to other critical switches in the cockpit), which makes sense [considering how close the lever is to the throttles](http://www.anft.net/f-14/f14-detail-cp-22xl.jpg) (The yellow-black-striped "slider" to the right of the throttles).